# Comment éviter le subjonctif imparfait dans une phrase commençant par « Bien que »

Tags: subjonctif

Je veux éviter le subjonctif imparfait parce qu'il donne à ma phrase une couleur soutenue que je ne recherche pas.

> Bien que les réformes religieuses et politiques d’Akhénaton *fussent* impondérables dans le règne d’Amenhotep III, la période d’Amarna est inextricablement liée à celui-ci.

Ce serait une erreur que de remplacer *fussent* par *furent* ou *étaient*, car (dans ce contexte) *bien que* demande le subjonctif. Mais je veux éviter le subjonctif imparfait. Comment devrais-je rephraser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut éviter l'emploi du subjonctif tout en gardant le même sens. Voici ma proposition: "Malgré l'impossibilité de prévoir les réformes religieuses et  politiques d'Akhénaton, pendant le règne d'Amenhotep III, la période d’Amarna est inextricablement liée à celui-ci".

Comment: C'est une bonne solution d'éviter la forme conjuguée. Et si on se sent l'âme en verve, on peut même se permettre d'employer le plus rare *nonobstant*.

Answer (score 4):

Le subjonctif passé.

> Bien que les réformes religieuses et politiques d’Akhénaton aient été imprévisibles pendant le règne d’Amenhotep III, la période d’Amarna est inextricablement liée à celui-ci.

(J'ai remplacé « impondérable » qui signifie « dont l'effet n'est pas calculable ni prévisible mais peut être déterminant » et est donc inapplicable ici, quelque chose ne peut avoir un effet que sur ce qui le suit, pas sur ce qui le précède.  Je ne suis pas pour autant sûr que « imprévisible » ait le sens désiré.)

A noter que c'est la forme classique aussi.  Les subjonctifs imparfait et plus-que-parfait ne s'employant qu'avec un verbe de principale au passé et « est liée » étant un présent, « fussent » et « eussent été » n'auraient pu convenir.

Answer (score 1):

Tu peux toujours utiliser le présent du subjonctif:

> Bien que les réformes religieuses et politiques d’Akhénaton *soient* impondérables

Comment: Pas vraiment, parce que j'essaie de dire qu'à l'époque du règne d'Amenhotep III, on ne pouvait pas prédire ce qui allait arriver dans le règne de son successeur Akhénaton. On ne dirait pas « À l'époque d'Amenhotep III, on ne peut pas prédire... », mais plutôt « À l'époque d'Amenhotep III, on ne pouvait pas prédire... »

Comment: @TheThunderChimp: Tu dois donc utiliser l'imparfait.

Comment: [Présent historique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Présent_historique)

Comment: @PapaPoule: Don't worry, I've done an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if you wanted to avoid only the subjunctive imperfect, or the imperfect altogether, but if the “simple” imperfect (de l'indicatif) (or past historic) is acceptable, you could perhaps also consider the following (please note also that, as in the other answers, I question somewhat your use of ’impondérables” and I would also agree that you might consider changing “dans” to “pendant”):

> Même si  les réformes religieuses et politiques d’Akhénaton
>   étaient/(furent)  ?_____ ? (imprévisibles/?inimaginables?) pendant le
>   règne d’Amenhotep III, la période d’Amarna est inextricablement liée à
>   celui-ci.